# Ext JS insertAdjacentHTML null when extending Ext.tree.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

i have a problem when extending Ext.tree.Panel in ext JS 4
I have this code :

```
Ext.define('Peps.tree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.pepstree',
});

Ext.create('Peps.tree', {
    renderTo:'selection_indicateur',
    id : 'pepstree',
    width:'500px',
    height:'500px'
});

Ext.create('Peps.tree', {
   renderTo:'selection_arborescence',
   id : 'pepstree2',
   width:'500px',
   height:'500px'
});
```

And when i execute i can see only one treepanel created and an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
```

This code is a minimal version of the real one, i hope solving the minimal code will solve everything.

What do i do wrong ? Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put your code into jsfiddle I dont get the error you are describing
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/VbTjx/embedded/result/

however you will notice that when expanding second level children on the second grid you dont get any children - so there is something wrong there, but I amnot sure if thats related to the issue you see.

Looks like the common prototype shares the root - which is not a good thing here.

Comment: I solved the Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null, it seems one of those renderTo was linked with a bad id. But i still have a problem, the 2 trees are like connected together http://jsfiddle.net/VbTjx/1/ here is a copy of my work and as you can see, the 2 trees have the same "store" but i specify 2 different roots, i maybe forgot to do something when extending the treepanel, but what ?

Comment: The roots are definitely shared between the trees, even though they are separate instances. I would forget about trying to reuse the tree definition - it looks like the prototype of the tree is being modified by the first instance - so don't go there! I would classify that as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

So i've found the problem, i don't know why but ext js needs to have the id of the viewconfig defined when extending a treepanel.

So i added in my initComponent() method this :

```
initComponent: function() {
    var id = Ext.id();
    Ext.apply(this, {
        viewConfig: {
            id: id + '-view'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find a post a sencha's forum about my problem here : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?189464-trees-connected-bug-when-extending-Ext.tree.Panel